# Delete Approval Process Metadata api

Tags: api, metadata, approval-process

I have a problem: I created aproval process using metadata api(metadata api description and examples here -> https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi), but when I trying to delete approval process by metadata api I have an error:

[image]

Here is method for deleting my own approval process(MbO_Form__c.MbO_ap_Approving_Achievements - name of process):

```
public static void deleteApprovalProcess() {
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();     
    List<MetadataService.DeleteResult> results = service.deleteMetadata(
            'ApprovalProcess',
            new String[] {'MbO_Form__c.MbO_ap_Approving_Achievements'}
            );      
    handleDeleteResults(results[0]);
}
```

and method for delete object by metadata:

```
public MetadataService.DeleteResult[] deleteMetadata(String type_x,String[] fullNames) { 
    MetadataService.deleteMetadata_element request_x = new MetadataService.deleteMetadata_element(); 
    request_x.type_x = type_x;
    request_x.fullNames = fullNames;
    MetadataService.deleteMetadataResponse_element response_x; 
    Map<String, MetadataService.deleteMetadataResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, MetadataService.deleteMetadataResponse_element>();
    response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
    WebServiceCallout.invoke(
            this,
            request_x,
            response_map_x,
            new String[] {endpoint_x, '', 'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata', 'deleteMetadata', 'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata', 'deleteMetadataResponse', 'MetadataService.deleteMetadataResponse_element'}
            ); 
    response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x'); 
    return response_x.result;
}
```

Please help me solve the following problem?

Comment: did u query and check if the approval process exists or not ?

Comment: I need to remove the approval with the help of Metadata api.
If I make a request using the metadata, the approvy finds, but does not use it more known as:

..................................................................................
 queryLayout.type_x = 'ApprovalProcess'; 
        queries.add(queryLayout);       
        MetadataService.FileProperties[] fileProperties = service.listMetadata(queries, METADATA_API_VERSION);
......................................................................